# How do I clean the inside of a keyboard that I spilled a drink into?

Tags: cleaning, technology

[My keyboard](http://www.cnet.com/products/microsoft-sculpt-ergonomic-desktop/) works fine but some of the keys hesitate to press. This makes typing really difficult.

I have not figured out how to take it apart since there are no screws at all on the front or back.

Comment: Who's the manufacturer of the keyboard?

Comment: I had it in the details, not sure why it was edited out. This is the keyboard in question: http://www.cnet.com/products/microsoft-sculpt-ergonomic-desktop/

Comment: @Bowen you can rollback the edit - click on the time of the last edit and choose from options there

Comment: I would leave the product specifics out because, as a common problem, it might be on topic for this site... but if you are looking for the location of the screws or something specific to repairing that device, it would likely be outside the scope of this site.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/742295/can-i-use-vodka-to-clean-my-keyboard Related on Superuser (don't use vodka)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Quick and easy: try to pop off offending key caps and *carefully* clean through the hole with a *damp* cotton swab. Though I'm not familiar with the Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Keyboard, most key caps (other than Space, Enter and Shift) can be removed by pulling on a hook made from a paper clip or with strong sewing thread pushed underneath.
2. If many keys are badly stuck and if the drink is completely water-soluble (e.g. soda) as opposed to a mixture (such as hot chocolate), the keyboard can be washed in *high purity* or *distilled* water (not tap water, rainwater or deionized water), even immersed in it. Of course, the keyboard will not be usable for a while.

   If the keyboard has a battery, as *all* wireless keyboards do, the battery *must* be removed first and not reinserted until the unit is completely dry, inside and out. It should not be plugged into a port until dry, either.

   To speed up drying, the keyboard can be rinsed in 99% ethanol or isopropanol, but that adds to the cost of repair.

Comment: To make it "true dry", you may keep your keyboard wrapped in a plastic bag with reasonable amount of silica-gel for some time. Plz do this after it is "almost dry" by using traditional drying methods ...

Comment: Is there a chance to break off the key completely? I haven't done this yet because I'm afraid of snapping the plastic.

Comment: 1. Silica gel is not magic -- it cannot remove water from the keyboard once the gel is saturated, and it would take a *large* amount of silica gel to absorb all the water. Better just keep the keyboard in a warm, dry place with air circulation.  2. Yes, you can break keys or key caps when removing them, but in my experience, either they'll pop off easily or (for the wider keys), not at all. Use care and don't force them with more than a kg (10 N, for the pedantic) force.

Comment: Since this is Lifehacks SE, use rice instead of silica gel.

Comment: Be careful with both rice and silica gel: they make fine powder when shaken or rubbed, which can jam mechanical parts.